# Have any of the masks of the Knights of Ren been seen before?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-legends, knights-of-ren

So far, we have seen seven Knights of Ren:

[image]

[image]

At least six of them have masks.  (The second from the right may or may not be sporting one.)

**Have any of their masks been seen before in the *Star Wars* saga?**

***Update:*** This is now a rather old question and many things are known now that were unknown at the time of *Force Awakens* (and I suspect the answer to the question can be confirmed as "no", although I would be happy to be surprised).  In any event, here is a better screen grab of the Knights of Ren from *Rise of Skywalker* — all donning masks:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking just about the films, or other canon/Legends sources?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh : Any source is fine.

Comment: Well, i didn't find anything, except [this site with a bunch of concept art featuring a lot of different Ren-like masks](http://starwarsallday.blogspot.sg/2015/12/concept-art-for-starwars-force-awakens.html). I could've sworn I saw a few of those masks in the film, I just can't match them up with the dark, rainy guys in the images.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no. The helmets are apparently custom creations of the Knights of Ren, each a unique confection intended to strike fear into their enemies.

That being said, at least one of the Knights, Trudgen, has incorporated elements from a known source seen elsewhere in the Star Wars movies, namely part of a Death Trooper helmet from Rogue One.

---

[image]
<sub><sup>[Rise of Skywalker: Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary)</sup></sub>

---

Several of the other helmets were original creations of LucasFilm Concept Artist Glyn Dillon who penned them as helmet concepts for the character that latterly became Kylo Ren, but was originally a Jedi-murdering Force-using bounty hunter known as *[the Jedi Killer](https://www.slashfilm.com/force-awakens-changes/3/)*.

[image]

<sub><sup>[The Art of Star Wars: The Force Awake](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens)</sup></sub>